# How to open a web view of a link from an api?

Tags: flutter, dart

See the image first:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LPST.jpg)

So i have made a news app using https://newsapi.org/s/google-news-in-api
Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: Center(
    child: isLoading
        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: newsData == null ? 0 : newsData.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/headlines"),
                child: Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  ),
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        child: Image.network(newsData[index]['urlToImage']),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          newsData[index]['title'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 23.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),

                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: 
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                newsData[index]['publishedAt'][11]
                                ),
                            ),

                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  semanticContainer: false,
                  color: Colors.white70,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

So how can i open the news website when the card is clicked/tapped in this app itself,
I mean how should i open the news website in this app rather than open it up in the browser using url_launcher

Note: I found a plugin "flutter_webview_plugin"
But still not able to implement it.
Also do remember that I need to keep the index number common for both the card and the source url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** add click event to image 
https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-add-on-click-event-to-image-in-flutter/

You can wrap you news image with GestureDetector and do action in onTap

```
GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyInAppWebView(webUrl: newsData[index][url],webRect: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 300, 300))));
                );
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/images/umbrella.png'),
                minRadius: 80,
                maxRadius: 120,
              ),
            ),
```

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappbrowser 
You can display in widget directly or

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyInAppWebView(webUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",webRect: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 300, 300))));
```

You can reference both situations in my full code 
the simple MyInAppWebView just pass webUrl and WebRect 
or you can reference complex demo (picture 2) in official site

```
class MyInAppWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  String webUrl;
  final Rect webRect;
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  MyInAppWebView({Key key, this.webUrl, this.webRect}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    InAppWebView webWidget = new InAppWebView(
        initialUrl: webUrl,
        initialHeaders: {},
        initialOptions: {},
        onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
          webView = controller;
        },
        onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
          print("InAppWebView.onLoadStart: $url");
          this.webUrl = url;
        },
        onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
          double prog = progress / 100;
          print('InAppWebView.onProgressChanged: $prog');
        });
    return Container(
      width: webRect.width,
      height: webRect.height,
      child: webWidget,
    );
  }
}
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappbrowser/flutter_inappbrowser.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyInAppWebView(webUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",webRect: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 300, 300))));
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded( child: MyInAppWebView(webUrl: "https://flutter.dev/", webRect: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 300, 300),)),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}


class MyInAppWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  String webUrl;
  final Rect webRect;
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  MyInAppWebView({Key key, this.webUrl, this.webRect}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    InAppWebView webWidget = new InAppWebView(
        initialUrl: webUrl,
        initialHeaders: {},
        initialOptions: {},
        onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
          webView = controller;
        },
        onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
          print("InAppWebView.onLoadStart: $url");
          this.webUrl = url;
        },
        onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
          double prog = progress / 100;
          print('InAppWebView.onProgressChanged: $prog');
        });
    return Container(
      width: webRect.width,
      height: webRect.height,
      child: webWidget,
    );
  }
}
```

example code demo

[image]

official demo

[image]

Comment: But u are not getting my point, I am calling data from an api. So how can. Call the same index number from list view to the url index

Comment: please try MyInAppWebView(webUrl: newsData[index]['url']  , I suppose you have url field.

Comment: Ya but index is declared inside the listview.builder so how can i call that index value in the MyAppWebView

Comment: I have edit my answer. you can see detail. basically, you can wrap you news image with GestureDetector and do action in onTap

Comment: I tried your method but with another plugin and it worked pretty well.
As i am just a learner i had forgot the use of keys in flutter. But yes after trying your code i got the required result thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try forceWebview option as explained in https://medium.com/@muaazmusthafa08/how-to-load-a-web-page-in-flutter-app-607fa9184e4a

Comment: I want to open the website within my app itself,  not in the browser